# Redimencionar imagem com php

Tags: php

estou tentanto colocar um script php para redimensionar imagens dinamicamente, até ai não tive problema. tenho uma pasta que fica salva as imagens que foram editadas pelo script e as imagens chegam certinho, só que eu queria que o nome da imagem também fosse gravado no banco de dados.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM foto WHERE foto = '6671.jpg' OR foto = '6672.jpg'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);    
    while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {     
    $img_origem = ImageCreateFromJpeg($linha['foto']);
    $largura = imagesx($img_origem);
    $altura = imagesy($img_origem);
    $nova_largura = 200;
    $nova_altura = $altura * $nova_largura / $largura;
    $img_destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nova_largura, $nova_altura);
    imagecopyresampled($img_destino, $img_origem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nova_largura, $nova_altura, $largura, $altura);
    $up = imageJPEG($img_destino,'teste/'. rand() . '.jpg', 85);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO foto (foto) VALUES ('" . $up . "')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);
    }
```

Comment: não entendi qual o problema com o teu script.

Comment: meu problema é na hora de inserir essa imagem redimensionada no banco, aquela variavel $up não pega o nome da imagem. o valor atribuido para ela é sempre 1. porem na minha pasta teste a imagem é guardada normamente.

Comment: Mas a função ImageJPEG não retorna o nome do arquivo de acordo com a documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: na verdade a função ImageJPEG retorna o nome correto, pelo menos na pasta teste ela é salva corretamente. mas se eu der um echo na variavel $up ela tem o valor de 1

Comment: Bianca, vc está salvando com nome rand(), mas tá inserindo um boolean no banco de valor 1. O que o mau humor disse é q na documentação o retorno da função é booleano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendendo melhor sua questão, temos que o índice de colisão usando `rand()` é muito grande. Então para melhorar seu código e diminuir esse índice de colisão seria interessante usar [`time()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_time.asp) concatenando com o `rand()` e a extensão do arquivo no nome de sua imagem. Desta forma, a colisão seria mínima. Veja:

```
$filenameRandon = date('Ymdhms').rand().'.jpg';
```

Agora veja abaixo como seu código ficaria:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foto WHERE foto = '6671.jpg' OR foto = '6672.jpg'";
$query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);    

while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {     
    $img_origem = ImageCreateFromJpeg($linha['foto']);
    $largura = imagesx($img_origem);
    $altura = imagesy($img_origem);
    $nova_largura = 200;
    $nova_altura = $altura * $nova_largura / $largura;
    $img_destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nova_largura, $nova_altura);
    imagecopyresampled($img_destino, $img_origem, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        $nova_largura, $nova_altura, $largura, $altura);

    // definindo o nome do arquivo
    $filenameRand = date('Ymdhms').rand().'.jpg'; 

    // salvando o arquivo na pasta específicada teste/
    $up = imageJPEG($img_destino,'teste/'. $filenameRand, 85);

    // verificação se a imagem foi salva corretamente
    if($up){

        // aqui você esta inserindo no banco o nome do seu arquivo gerado com $filenameRand
        $sql = "INSERT INTO foto (foto) VALUES ('" . $filenameRand . "')";
        $query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);

    } else {
        echo "A imagem naum foi salva";
    }

}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, Muito obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Seu código não faz muito sentido, mas para resolver teu problema, recomendo trocar

```
$up = imageJPEG($img_destino,'teste/'. rand() . '.jpg', 85);
```

Por

```
$up = $linha['foto'];
```

Pois a função `imageJPEG` retorna um `boolean` indicando se a função foi executada com sucesso. De acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagejpeg.php)

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda :D

Answer (score 0):

Como o mau humor citou, embora a função salve com o nome rand, o retorno dela é boolean 1 pra caso tenha conseguido salvar e 0 pra caso tenha dado erro. $up sempre será 1 se conseguir salvar e 0 caso dê erro no salvamento. Se você quiser o nome que vc gerou pra usar no sql, salve rand numa variável e passe pro nome do arquivo e para o sql.

Mude:

```
$up = imageJPEG($img_destino,'teste/'. rand() . '.jpg', 85);
$sql = "INSERT INTO foto (foto) VALUES ('" . $up . "')";
$query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);
```

Para:

```
$nome_rand = rand();
$salvouCerto = imageJPEG($img_destino,'teste/'. $nome_rand . '.jpg', 85);
if($salvouCerto)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO foto (foto) VALUES ('" . $nome_rand  . "')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);
}else
{
//Exibe algum erro dizendo que não conseguiu salvar
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda :D